# How to find numbers that are North South East and West of a number in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, 2d

My program so far can find numbers that are north south east and west of a specified position however it gives me an error if i input numbers into the program that have no n,s,e,w values. Can anybody help?

this is an example of my north method

```
public static void fetchN(int[][]array , int rw, int cl)
{
    int north = 0;
    int east = 0;
    int south = 0;
    int west = 0;
    for(int r = 0; r < array.length; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < array[r].length; c++)
        {

            north = array[rw-1][cl];
        }
    }
    System.out.print("North :: "+north);
}
```

Comment: What is the error, and what input(s) cause this error?

Comment: What is North of `array[0][0]`?

Comment: Is this supposed to be [tag:java]?  There is no language tag.

Comment: yes it is java also the array is filled in with random numbers and user inputed row size and column size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most likely getting an out of bounds exception. When you check north, you need to check that `rw-1>=0` because you can't reference a negative index in an array. Likewise on the west method, you need to check that `cl-1>=0`. On the south and east methods, you need to check that you're not going out of the length of your array. On south you need to check that your `rw+1<= array.length`, on east you need to check that `cl+1<= array[rw].length`.

It also seems like your method has some redundant code. Neither of your for loops are accomplishing anything here, and you're initializing unnecessary variables. Here's a rewritten version of your fetchN method.

```
public static void fetchN(int[][]array , int rw, int cl)
{  
  if(rw-1>=0){
      int north = array[rw-1][cl];
      System.out.print("North :: "+north);
  }
  else{
      System.out.print("There is no North coordinate");
  }

}
```

Comment: it didnt work because it is still giving me the same error

Comment: (out of bounds) public static void fetchN(int[][]array , int rw, int cl)
     { 
     int north=0;
     for(int r = 0; r < array.length; r++)
   {
   for(int c = 0; c < array[r].length; c++)
   {
   north = array[rw-1][cl]; 
      if(rw-1>=0)
      {
      north = array[rw-1][cl];
      System.out.print("North :: "+north);
      }
     else
     {
      System.out.print("There is no North coordinate");
      }

    }
 }
    }

Comment: nvm than you very much